# What is the formatter/syntax highlighter to work with ejs (embedded javascript) templates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, templates, ejs

For the project I use EJS (http://ejs.co/) as express templating engine. It is good and easy to use, but editing files is a bit of a problem - text highlight is worse than average and I could not find any tools to auto format files.

My main IDE is VS Code and I have tried Atom.

For VS code I used QassimFarid.ejs-language-support, which has way more installs than all others and I found it lacking. Tried DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support, but it is getting confused with my code pretty soon too.

For Atom I go with language-ejs (atom.io/packages/language-ejs) which is very good.

Sadly, both VS Code and Atom do not have any autoformat capabilities (read *packages*), and pure JS formatters are confused with ejs markup.

What do you use to format your ejs templates?

P.S.
I do not mind trying some other IDEs/editors or even some standalone formatters.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite subjective, so I can't really offer a definitive answer. But I get the feeling you're just using the base text editor rather than installing packages.

Both VS Code and Atom come with package systems. In VS Code you can click on the "Extensions" icon on the left hand panel (under the debug item). This will let you search for extensions that offer things such as auto-complete and syntax highlighting. Just by typing in "ejs" there are 4 different syntax highlighting and evaluators.

Atom also has a similar system to search for and install packages. From here you should be able to find one which suits your needs for EJS.

Comment: Hallo Elliot! Thanks for answering. For VS code I used QassimFarid.ejs-language-support, which has way more installs than all others. I found it lacking. Tried DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support, but it is getting confused with my code pretty soon too. They  both are nice, though, for simple templates.

Comment: And they both do not provide an option to format the file. Failing to find right extensions, for favorite IDEs I was hoping that there are some other editors that have them.

Comment: For Atom I go with language-ejs (https://atom.io/packages/language-ejs) which is very good, but do not have any formater

Comment: And even the best atom-beautify does not work as well as I hoped (as it does for pure JS files, for example)

Comment: Based on all of that, I think you should update your question to contain those requirements. At the moment you've just asked for a very subjective answer, you'd be better off asking for editors (or editor packages) which meet all of those needs.